# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm making a web application using WEB API 2.
Previously, my project ran fine without any errors. Errors only came after I had updated my nuget packages to the lastest version.

Currently, when I start my web application, it throws me an error:

[image]

This is the command where exception is thrown (in Startup.cs)

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ApiRouteConfig.Register);
```

I've tried reinstalling WEB API 5.2.3 again and again but no luck. The error kept happening.

Here is my packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Autofac.SignalR2" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="JWT" version="1.3.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Nustache" version="1.16.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="ToolKit-DataAnnotations" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

I've search for many solutions on internet but didn't work for me. I don't know what is going on with my project. It cost me one day with nothing.

My development environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3
- Net Framework 4.6.1

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This has occured because some assembly still references `System.Net.Http` version 4.0.0.0 while you have upgraded it and version 4.0.0.0 no longer exist.

Things you can try:

Search for `System.Net.Http.dll` in your project folder. It will usually be in `packages`. `Right click on dll > Properties > Goto Details tab > Find Product Version` there.

Open App.config, add the following code. `assemblyBinding` should come under `configuration > runtime`. Replace `current_version` with the version you found in the previous step.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http"
                              publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="current_version"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This will redirect any call to version `4.0.0.0` to the `current_version` dll at `runtime`.